# python cant' see the imported libs installed to separate venv, but pip list shows them installed

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

AFter creating venv "twitter-de" and installing into it pandas, tweepy, s3fs, I tried running the code but it gives error saying "lib not found"

```
source twitter-de-env/Scripts/activate

#checking if libs installed
pip list | grep s3fs
s3fs                                     2023.9.2
```

the code:

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import json
from datetime import datetime
import s3fs


def run_twitter_etl():
        #some processing here using twitter api
```

error:

```
    import tweepy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

but it does not see the installed libs. how to fix it?